# The name Host does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am following this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/working-with-sql?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio I get the following error message:
The Name Host does not exist in the current context

Here is what my Program.cs file looks like

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MvcMovie.Data;
using MvcMovie.Models;
using System;

namespace MvcMovie
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                try
                {
                    SeedData.Initialize(services);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
                }
            }

            host.Run();

        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

There is a red line under Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

Comment: Try WebHost instead

Comment: When I do that I get a red line under ConfigureWebHostDefaults instead in WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET Core 3? It's in the URL but that's the default now. Can you show the contents of the `.csproj`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1 I don't see it here. What version of .netcore are you using?

Comment: Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.10" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Comment: Are you using EF core tools?

Comment: I don't think so. I am using Entity framework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tutorial you've referenced is set to use 3.0, but the contents of your .csproj show that you are using 2.1. `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder` is not available in 2.1, which leaves you with two options:

1. Switch to the 2.1 version of the tutorial, which uses `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder`. This can be done using the "Version" selector of the ASP.NET Core docs pages.
2. Use the 3.0 (or 3.1) version of the tutorial and configure your project accordingly. For that, you just need an appropriate version of the SDK and Visual Studio.

If you *can*, use the 3.1 version. This is the recommended, LTS version.

Comment: They have apparently removed the versions of the tutorial for ASP.Net Core versions prior to 3.0 and Visual Studio 2017 does not support 3.0 so VS 2017 users are not supported by the tutorial.